# Can't load http after creating MAMP localhost

Tags: http, mamp

I'm currently working on http://thomaskinkadegallery.com - however, now that I have set up a localhost (http://thomaskinkadegallery.com:8888) on my local machine, I cannot access the remote server anymore.  I get a page timeout.  I checked the page on another computer, it's working just fine.

What is blocking the site on my machine?

Comment: Did you happen to have edited the `hosts` file to make that url point to your local machine?